# Compact subgroups have determinant $1$ or $-1$

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, determinant, compactness

The following question is from 'Matrix Groups for Undergraduates' by Kristopher Tapp:

Let $G \subset GL_n(\mathbb R)$ be a compact subgroup.

(1) Prove that every element of $G$ has determinant $1$ or $-1$.
(2) Must it be true that $G \subset O(n)?$
*Hint: Consider conjugates of $O(n).$*

Attempt: I know the relevant definition of closed (i.e. if a sequence of matrices in $G$ has a limit in $GL_n(\mathbb R)$, then that limit must lie in $G$). I also know a matrix element is bounded if (when it is regarded as an element of $\mathbb R^{n^2}$) it has finite norm. I just cannot really see how these give us any information about the determinant.

As for $(2)$, following the hint and considering a conjugate of $O(n)$, when we consider $A \in O(n)$ and $B \in GL_n(\mathbb R)$ we see that 
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split} 
\det BAB^{-1} &= (\det B)(\det A)(\det B^{-1}) \\ 
&= (\pm 1)(\det B)(\det B^{-1}) \\ 
&= \pm 1 
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

so we see that conjugates are in the group, implying it is a normal subgroup, but what does this tell us about G?

I'm definitely missing a lot here, any help would be appreciated, thanks all.

Comment: I haven't thought it fully through, but it might be worth looking at $(G^n)_{n=1}^\infty$? If $|\operatorname{det}(G)| > 1$, then this determinant is going to blow up. If $|\operatorname{det}(G)| < 1$, then replace $G$ with $G^{-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $G$ is compact, then $\det(G)$ is a compact subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},\times)$. There are only two such subgroups: $\{1\}$ and $\{\pm1\}$.

For the other question, consider the group$$\left(\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&-2\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}\right\},.\right).$$It is compact, but not a subgroup of $O(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I think I understand. I was wondering though, how do you conclude that $\det(G)$ is a compact subgroup of $(\mathbb R, \times)$? Is this just using the fact that $\det$ is continuous?

Comment: @K.Reeves Indeed. The image of a compact set by a continuous function is always compact.

Comment: I can't tell what your sequence of matrices outside of $O(2)$ is.

Comment: @ziggurism Since there are no sequences in my answer, that's not strange.

Comment: I somehow read a ... in that list of punctuation, and assumed it was a sequence. I see now there is only a comma and period. Sorry, my mistake. So $\mathbb{Z}/2$\subset O(2)$ is a finite subset, thus compact. And you conjugated by a change of basis matrix into a nonorthogonal basis, so the resulting group is not orthogonal?

Comment: @ziggurism Yes. To be more precise, I took as my starting point the group$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}\right\},$$which is compact (since it is finite, as you wrote). But it is also a subgroup of $O(2,\mathbb{R})$. Then I replaced it with$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1},\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\right\},$$thereby getting the group that I mentioned.